# How to find the probability of something given its expected value

Tags: probability

Consider the following game of chance. You toss a biased (i.e. not fair) coin twice. You
win £4 if two heads occur and you win £1 if one head occurs. You lose £2 if two tails
occur. The game’s expected winnings are -£0.50. Find the probabilities of the biased
coin (i.e. the probability for observing head and the probability for observing tail in a
toss).

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: **Hint.** The expected winnings are a weighted sum of the payoffs: the payoff for each case (possibly negative) times the probability associated with that case, summed up over all possible cases (two heads, one head, no heads).

Comment: Still not quite sure how to go about this, I know how to calculate the expected winnings but is there a formula to use to check for the probability of heads or tails

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the probability of heads. Then $1-p$ is the probability of tails. Can you write down the formula for expected payout? Then you should be able to solve for $p$.

Comment: expected payout would be (4 x p x (1-p))+ (1 x p x (1-p)) + (1 x p x (1-p)) - (2 x p x (1-p)) = -0.50

so how do i figure out p(H) and p(T) from this?

Comment: That's not quite right: 2 H is $p^2$ etc...

But once you write that down, it's a quadratic equation in $p$, and you can use the quadratic formula.